# use hooks in git to import and export to cvs

Tags: git, cvs

i would like to know if this is possible:

- create a shared git repository that connects to cvs
- post two hooks to it:

  1. everytime anyone pulls from it, it imports from the cvs repository
  2. everytime anyone pushes to it, it exports to the cvs repository

basically create a 'lazy mirror' of a cvs repository that is completely transparent to the git users

if this is not possible what are the best method to create a cvs mirror?

ps. is git-cvsserver usable? besides the commits, checkouts and updates, can it merge two branches?

Comment: how did this work for you? i want to do exactly this, this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git-cvsserver`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cvsserver.html) has limitations:

> - Currently cvsserver works over SSH connections for read/write clients, and over pserver for anonymous CVS access.
> - CVS clients cannot tag, branch or perform GIT merges.
> - `git-cvsserver` maps GIT branches to CVS modules. This is very different from what most CVS users would expect since in CVS modules usually represent one or more directories.

You can find [best practices for using Git with CVS here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-cvs), with a [full git-cvs setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225).
You can try and add to this setup a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) and see if a `git cvsexportcommit` can work from there.

Comment: if it cannot tag, then it is seriously flawed for what i am looking for.. (eclipse cvs tag and merge are the two actions needed besides the basic ones) //

that link is the bible for git-cvs interaction, this question comes up as a follow up to see if anyone implemented it as an automated method to keep a git repo synchronize (thanks for the hooks link.. starting point found) //

.. or for that mather any other method to have synchronized git and cvs repos