# how can I customize git's merge commit message?

Tags: git, git-merge

Every time I do a merge I need for a merge commit to be generated and I would like it to have more than just the summary of all the commits.

**My question is how can I format git-fmt-merge-msg or what determines this automated message** (I can do this manually after a commit by amending it and using git-log --pretty=format:'...')

For example I would like to format it as such:

```
 Merge branch 'test'  
    * test:  
      [BZ: #123] fifth commit subject  
      [BZ: #123] fourth commit subject  
      [BZ: #123] third commit subject  
      [BZ: #123] second commit subject  
      [BZ: #123] first commit subject  

 __________________________________________
 Merge details:  
     [BZ: #123] fifth commit subject  
               at 2010-06-30 11:29:00 +0100  
       - fifth commit body  

     [BZ: #123] fourth commit subject  
               at 2010-06-30 11:22:17 +0100  
       - fourth commit body  

     [BZ: #123] third commit subject  
               at 2010-06-30 11:21:43 +0100  
       - third commit body  

     [BZ: #123] second commit subject  
               at 2010-06-30 11:21:30 +0100  
       - second commit body  

     [BZ: #123] first commit subject  
               at 2010-06-30 11:29:57 +0100  
       - first commit body
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wanted to do something just like this. I didn't find any reasonable way to get `git fmt-merge-msg` to work. I think it doesn't work the way I was hoping (passing in a completely custom text to use for the message). So instead I figured out another way using the `-no-commit` and `commit -F` commands. The output is of course customizable but it reflects almost exactly what you said you wanted the output to be.

Sample Commit Message Output:

```
Merge branch fix4 into master

::SUMMARY::
Branch fix4 commits:
Add fix4b-4
Add fix4b-3
Add fix4b-2
Add fix4b-1

Branch master commits:
fix4b-5 on master

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
::DETAILS::
commit < 98ffa579e14610b3566e1a3f86556a04dc95a82b
Author: -----
Date:   Fri Aug 17 17:23:26 2018 -0400

    fix4b-5 on master

commit > 7e386dddee16a7c2588954d25dd6793cdaa1b562
Author: -----
Date:   Fri Aug 17 15:18:17 2018 -0400

    Add fix4b-4

    use log output as commit message

    commit 2e630b1998312ec1093d73f9fe77b942407f45e8
    Author: -----
    Date:   Fri Aug 17 15:15:28 2018 -0400

        Add fix4b-3

commit > 2e630b1998312ec1093d73f9fe77b942407f45e8
Author: -----
Date:   Fri Aug 17 15:15:28 2018 -0400

    Add fix4b-3

commit > c9bb199be49c17ca739d019d749263314f05fc46
Author: -----
Date:   Fri Aug 17 15:15:27 2018 -0400

    Add fix4b-2

commit > 5b622a935c9d078c7d0ef9e195bccf1f98cce5e4
Author: -----
Date:   Fri Aug 17 15:15:27 2018 -0400

    Add fix4b-1
```

And the usage would be:

```
$ git mergelogmsg branch-name
```

I'll copy the alias here:

```
[alias]
    mergelogmsg = "!f() { var=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && printf 'Merge branch %s into %s\n\n::SUMMARY::\nBranch %s commits:\n' $1 $var $1 > temp_merge_msg && git log --format=format:'%s' $var..$1 >> temp_merge_msg && printf '\n\nBranch %s commits:\n' $var >> temp_merge_msg && git log --format=format:'%s' $1..$var >> temp_merge_msg && printf '\n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\n::DETAILS::\n' >> temp_merge_msg && git log --left-right $var...$1 >> temp_merge_msg && git merge --no-ff --no-commit $1 && git commit -eF temp_merge_msg; rm -f temp_merge_msg;}; f"
```

If you want to copy and paste it to customize it, use the above. The below version has line breaks which you do not want but I'll use to explain what I'm doing:

```
[alias]
1   mergelogmsg = "!f() { var=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && 
2        printf 'Merge branch %s into %s\n\n::SUMMARY::\nBranch %s commits:\n' $1 $var $1 > temp_merge_msg && 
3        git log --format=format:'%s' $var..$1 >> temp_merge_msg && 
4        printf '\n\nBranch %s commits:\n' $var >> temp_merge_msg && 
5        git log --format=format:'%s' $1..$var >> temp_merge_msg && 
6        printf '\n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\n::DETAILS::\n' >> temp_merge_msg && 
7        git log --left-right $var...$1 >> temp_merge_msg && 
8        git merge --no-ff --no-commit $1 && 
9        git commit -eF temp_merge_msg; rm -f temp_merge_msg;}; f"
```

Alright...

**Line 1** starts the custom function as a bash shell script so git knows it's not a git command. It sets the current branch (master if you are merging a different branch into master) to a variable so we can use it later.
**Line 2** prints the first line using the current branch and the branch name you've given the original command (just as you would in a normal merge command). It writes this to a temp file.
**Line 3** gets the log of the commits in the incoming branch that are not in the current branch, and writes out only the subjects of those commits to the temp file.
**Line 4** prints the next line to temp.
**Line 5** gets the log of the commits in the current branch that are not in the incoming branch, and writes out only the subjects of those commits to the temp file.
**Line 6** prints a little horizontal separator between the summary and detail portions.
**Line 7** gets the log of all the commits in the current branch and incoming branch back to the time just after they branched off from each other, or last shared an ancestor. The left-right gives an arrow that shows which branch the commit comes from. < means current branch and > means incoming branch.
**Line 8** executes a merge command with the incoming branch with no fast-forward (so you get a commit) and with no commit (so you have to write one yourself... ah but you don't!)
**Line 9** executes the commit command with the `-e` and `-F` parameters to allow for editing and to tell the commit to populate the message with the text in the specified file. Once you've finished the commit message as desired, it commits the merge and deletes the temp file.

Tada! The two `;` at the end of that long command make it so the printf functions do not write out to the console, only to the file.

Comment: This is awesome!! It fits perfectly with the question and is can be easily customized. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I've already customized it a bit more. I made it just for a particular project but I might use it for all merges.

Answer (score 56):

I'm aware this isn't answering the original question, but for the benefit of git noobs like myself who reach this page because it's currently the first Google result for "git change merge commit message", I'll mention that it is possible to:

```
git commit --amend -m"New commit message"
```

to change the commit message of a merge commit without losing the link to any of the parents of the merge commit.

Comment: It made `git log --graph` stopped drawing branch graph.

Comment: If you just want to change the default merge commit from "merged branch ... into master", try using `git merge --no-edit -m "your-custom-commit-message"`

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question. No matter what queries google directs here, this should not be the top answer. It possibly shouldn't even be an answer to this question at all.

Comment: @Jasper Technically correct, but it's hardly my fault as the answerer that the title doesn't accurately capture the question in the body text. It's also hardly my fault that apparently people find this helpful enough for it to rise to the top. Having used SO for a while now (and having sufficient reputation to do so, in no small part due to this particular answer), nowadays I would probably edit the question instead, both to clarify the title and to add a link to a related Q&A.

Comment: In my opinion, it's the answerer's fault for not attempting to answer the question, but instead answering a question that was never asked. (It wouldn't have been so bad if this question hadn't been self-answered, but that doesn't change anything.) Perhaps a comment with a link to the question that is similar but different would be a better idea.

Comment: @Jasper I would definitely do that today, but this was my first contribution here so I (1) didn't have a clue and (2) only had access to the answer box and not much else. If you are suggesting to fix this now, and you can think of a way to do so without screwing over all the people that Google is going to continue directing here, I'm all ears.

Comment: NOTE: make sure you do NOT amend your commits after pushing!

Answer (score 24):

Looks like as of version [Git 1.7.8](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt) you can do `git merge --edit ...`
to specify the commit message.

And as of [1.7.10](https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt), dropping into edit mode will be the default behavior

> From this release on, the "git merge" command in an interactive session will start an editor when it automatically resolves the merge for the user to explain the resulting commit, just like the "git commit" command does when it wasn't given a commit message.

*(though I'm not seeing it on in msysgit on windows)*.

Answer (score 18):

I've found there are two ways for solving this problem

*note*: don't use both at the same time, as if the commit fails to merge it will add the log again to the bottom.

*personal note*: I'm using the first solution as it relies entirely on git's hooks and config properties, instead of an external script.
For a real solution one would have to extend a git command named 'fmt-merge-msg' that generates the oneline descriptions when passing the --log option (if you really need this solution you'll have to create your own patch (for git) and compile it from source).

**1. using prepare-commit-message as VonC [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148863/how-can-i-customize-gits-merge-commit-message/3149262#3149262)**
 this solution has the problem that you need to interrupt the commit and then commit manually

setting an alias that will build the desired commit message:

```
[alias]  
lm = log --pretty=format:'%s%n   by %C(yellow)%an%Creset (%ad)%n %n%b' --date=local
```

creating the prepare-commit-msg hook by creating an executable prepare-commit-msg in $GIT_DIR/hooks/ (example script below)

```
#!/bin/sh
#...

case "$2,$3" in  
  merge,)  
  echo "Merge details:" >> $1  
  echo "" >> $1  
  git lm ORIG_HEAD..MERGE_HEAD >> "$1" ;;  
*) ;;  
esac
```

one should define an alias commit msg such as

```
[alias]  
m = merge --no-ff --no-commit
```

**2. using a custom command that will generate the merge automatically**
(using the lm alias created in 1.)

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ""
echo "merge with commit details -- HEAD..$1"
git merge --no-ff --no-log -m "`git lm HEAD..$1`" --no-commit $1
```

and then execute a rather rigid command:

```
./cmd-name <branch to merge>
```

if you still wish to have the oneline description of the commits you'll need to add new commands or whatever to the -m argument (if you use --log then it will be generated on the bottom)

Comment: OK, great.  But frankly - this is far more difficult than it should be.

Comment: a much better answer was posted! check out the accepted one

Answer (score 10):

Once you merge your `<branch A>` to `<branch B>`, git will automatically commit a message saying "merge branch `<branch A>` into `<branch B>`.

If you want to customize git's merge commit message you can try:

```
$ git commit --amend -m "Your merge message"
```

This command will update your git's merge commit message to your commit message.

you can also try :

```
$ git merge <branch A> --no-commit
```

it will merge your `<branch B>` with `<branch A>`, with list of  `<Branch B>'s` commit and commit messages

If it fails to do fast-forward, then you will get something like this:

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

# check this with git status 
$ git status
```

It will show you, your commits are already added to stage but not yet commited so, you can commit them without running `git add`:

```
$ git commit -m "your merge commit message"
```

If you want to change `<branch B>`'s last commit message then again you can try:

```
$ git commit --amend -m "your new commit message"
```

But, generally, we don't update other commit messages, unless they are incorrect.

Suppose, you get conflict after git merge, then simply resolve your conflict and do:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "your commit message"
```

Comment: Why would you do an `--amend` on a commit that hasn't happened yet, in the last line of your answer? Shouldn't it just be `git commit -m "your commit message"`?

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing it out. It should be git commit -m "your commit message" since no commits are done for merge.

Comment: "since no commits are done for merge" when you specify the `--no-commit` flag, as you have done :-)

Comment: here, git merge b --no-commit will merge branch b to branch a, with all branch b commits(which is obvious) and with branch b's commit messages. It will not add extra commit messages like: "merged branch b with branch a"

Comment: If your merge is not fast-forward, you will get message like "Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested". Now, you don't need to run ```git add .```, But, directly you can commit the merge using ```git commit -m "your commit message"```

Answer (score 7):

There's also a `--log` option for `git-merge` now, which does half of what you want - it places the shortlog (commit summaries) in the merge message. A full solution will have to use a hook like in VonC's answer, though.

Comment: well I already have that option set globally, hooks won't do the trick as they do not activate during the merge (unless you stop it with --no-commit)

Comment: "hooks won't do the trick as they do not activate during the merge (unless you stop it with --no-commit)"; that a good question in itself: why no hook is being activating during the commit part of a merge?

Comment: @VonC: I think that's deliberate, actually - from a quick skim of the source, merge calls `commit_tree` directly.

Comment: The -m option is useful with --log. Also, for noobs like myself, don't use the --oneline option when examining the resulting log of the branch you merged into (using --log), otherwise you'll see just the merge commit message and not the individual commit messages of the merged branch.

Answer (score 5):

You could try defining a [**prepare-commit-msg** hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (the [sample one](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54e85e7af1ac9e9a92888060d6811ae767fea1bc/templates/hooks--prepare-commit-msg.sample) does generate some custom "default commit messages")

Comment: Works great up to a point, I have to merge with --no-commit and only then commit, otherwise the prepare-commit-msg hook doesn't seem to run (merge_msg is standard) .. I would like for the merge full details to be added automatically, as these are the commits that i submit to CVS

Comment: @shil88: did you try and see if the `commit-msg` hook was activated during a `git merge`?

Comment: @shil88: just realized I have already answered your first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817897/use-hooks-in-git-to-import-and-export-to-cvs): did you finally manage to implement a hook for keeping git and cvs repo in synch?

Comment: @VonC sorry did not had enough reputation to comment on answers, but I implemented a CVSNT postcommand hook that after a small delay forces the 'main' Git repo to perform a cvsimport... still tweaking it though, I will post my solution when it is fully usable (committing automatically is a really bad idea and for now I prefer committing from my local repo)

Comment: @shil88: posting your solution to this other question would be very helpful :) And you will be able to select it as the official solution too. (Even if it is your own solution)

Comment: @VonC commit-msg hook does not activate

Comment: @shil88: darn... Is there any hook alive during a git merge?!

Comment: @VonC doesn't seem to be any, tried post-commit and update, neither seemed to work (used a simple echo "bla" in the hooks to check if they are active)

Comment: @VonC what I need is to modify the git-fmt-merge-msg command, but I'm guessing that is not customizable (at least easily)

Comment: @VonC I'm just going to create a command that produces my full commit msg and run it with -m option... I'm sure that will be the workable solution

Comment: @shil88: interesting. if you can update your question with yuyr solution, I will post the main principle in my edited answer.

Comment: I didn't finish it today, cause work got in the way, but as soon as there is a working solution I'll post it here

Comment: @shil88: no problem, and no rush (at least on my side ;) I'll be there)

Comment: FYI, using Git 1.9.2 on Windows, I *do* see `prepare-commit-msg` being executed for merge commits without conflicts. However, I can confirm that `commit-msg` is not called in that case.

Comment: on windows, using tortoiseGit, there is no `prepare-commit-msg` hook, only `start-commit-hook` and no matter what the hook script is, I get a windows popup error: `%1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: @vsync if it is interpreted by the Git bash (even on Windows), try `$1`, not `%1`: `$1` will be replaced by the first argument, while `%1` would not (when interpreted in a git bash)

Comment: I don't even write `%1` anywhere.. it shows this error message even if the hook script is completely empty or has `echo "hello"` or whatever. I made sure it's using that file, because when I delete the hook script (from `.git/hooks/` I get a message the file cannot be found. pretty bizarre.

Comment: @vsync Strange: can you make that a question on its own?

Comment: ok, I will post it. I just assumed nobody would know so I didn't :)

Comment: Sheesh, what a lot of hoops.  Git has so many bizarre options everywhere, and yet `git merge --log` omits the rather obvious `--format=` ... 
and now we're 6 years on since this was asked.

Answer (score 4):

Coming late to the party, but nowadays we can just use
`git merge --squash <branch>`
to merge another branch into a single commit on my current branch **and prepopulating our commit message** with all the merged commit messages -- and the detailed messages, too, not just the one-liners.
I looked for ages for this command.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or does this act like a fast forward where you lose the branch context? I just tried it and maybe I used it wrong. The command you give itself doesn't seem to commit the merge, but then i ran git merge and it just did a fast forward. I'm curious about what's going on here, or how to use it as you describe.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. The answer should be general enough to be able to do a “real merge” as well, not just a squash merge which is really a rebase (with squash) and fast-forward. The question only asks about the merge commit message template.

Comment: @Guildenstern: granted, this only works with squash merges -- which was my requirement when I went looking back in 2018.  
:shrug:  
I'm letting this answer stand in hopes of helping others that are looking for a squash merge with a prepopulated commit message.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of `git merge --squash` mentioned in [Christian Severin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158371/christian-severin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333256/6309), you now have the config `merge.suppressDest` as a new way to customize a (small part of the) commit message.

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/341a196ab6603aa7be709812132fd906a3d2359c/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> learned to selectively omit " `into <branch>`" at the end of the title of default merge message with `merge.suppressDest` configuration.

See [commit 6e6029a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6029a82acdb3d785eef15dc798f4d86c4ea445) (29 Jul 2020), and [commit 2153192](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21531927e4e1b9fdf524983414ee59558cb4f3d6) (30 Jul 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 341a196](https://github.com/git/git/commit/341a196ab6603aa7be709812132fd906a3d2359c), 01 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fmt-merge-msg`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6029a82acdb3d785eef15dc798f4d86c4ea445): allow merge destination to be omitted again
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Linus Torvalds</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>

> In Git 2.28, we stopped special casing '`master`' when producing the default merge message by just removing the code to squelch "`into 'master'`" at the end of the message.
>
> Introduce multi-valued `merge.suppressDest` configuration variable that gives a set of globs to match against the name of the branch into which the merge is being made, to let users specify for which branch fmt-merge-msg's output should be shortened.
> When it is not set, '`master`' is used as the sole value of the variable by default.
>
> The above move mostly reverts the pre-2.28 default in repositories that have no relevant configuration.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6e6029a82acdb3d785eef15dc798f4d86c4ea445/Documentation/config/fmt-merge-msg.txt#L12):

> ### `merge.suppressDest`
>
> By adding a glob that matches the names of integration
> branches to this multi-valued configuration variable, the
> default merge message computed for merges into these
> integration branches will omit " `into <branch name>`" from
> its title.
>
> An element with an empty value can be used to clear the list
> of globs accumulated from previous configuration entries.
> When there is no `merge.suppressDest` variable defined, the
> default value of `master` is used for backward compatibility.

And:

> ### [`Revert "fmt-merge-msg`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21531927e4e1b9fdf524983414ee59558cb4f3d6): stop treating `master` specially"

> This reverts [commit 489947cee5095b168cbac111ff7bd1eadbbd90dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489947cee5095b168cbac111ff7bd1eadbbd90dd), which stopped treating merges into the '`master`' branch as special when preparing the default merge message.
> As the goal was not to have any single branch designated as special, it solved it by leaving the "`into <branchname>`" at the end of the title of the default merge message for any and all branches.
> An obvious and easy alternative to treat everybody equally could have been to remove it for every branch, but that involves loss of information.
>
> We'll introduce a new mechanism to let end-users specify merges into which branches would omit the "`into <branchname>`" from the title of the default merge message, and make the mechanism, when unconfigured, treat the traditional '`master`' special again, so all the changes to the tests we made earlier will become unnecessary, as these tests will be run without configuring the said new mechanism.

Comment: But how do you use `merge.suppressDest`?! Documentation just says a glob and multi-valued configuration variable - but gives no example. If I put `[merge]  suppressDest = main` in git config file it still doesn't suppress it. And what if I don't want to suppress it - which is actually what I want...? Terrible documentation...

Comment: @TheStoryCoder You can see an [example here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6e6029a82acdb3d785eef15dc798f4d86c4ea445/t/t6200-fmt-merge-msg.sh#L555-L562). master or now main might still be the default value (so preserved). I agree, the documentation is confusing.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Actual examples: [merge-latest script](https://github.com/AdamVig/dotfiles/blob/1d4231193d10ca7a3022fd1b2b6a1922e0d8fde6/bin/merge-latest#L27-L29)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple bash function that set's a default message and adds your argument.
It opens your editor with the `--edit` switch if you want make changes.

edit ~/.bashrc or bash_aliases. (Don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`) to apply changes in your bashrc

```
function mergedevelop()
{
    git merge --no-ff --edit -m "master <-- develop: $1" develop;
}
```

use:

`mergedevelop "PR #143..."` to have message:

master <-- develop: PR #143...

Answer (score 0):

You can override or customize a merge message during the merge with the command below:

```
git merge <branch> -m "<merge message>"
```

It was tested on git version 2.34, you can find it on the documentation by typing "git merge --help" if you have git installed, or at [git-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) at the time of this answer.