# How to change default commit message, when occurs merge via git bash

Tags: git

When exists unpushed commit and need to update repository, git create local commit with name:
Merge branch 'master' of http://oururl.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/ProjectName
It is possible to replace this message with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write a own message before the commit gets done you can use `git merge --edit` since version 1.7.8. Previously to this version you would need to `amend` the commit and change it's message afterwards (`git commit --amend`).

But if you want to change the default message provided by git I would take a look in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148863/how-can-i-customize-gits-merge-commit-message) and it's answers.