# Preserve automatic `git merge` message when passing custom message using `-m` option

Tags: git, git-merge

I use `git merge --no-edit ...` in a script.

When doing `git merge --no-edit ...`, git generates an automatic commit message like:

- "Merge branch X into Y" or
- "Merge commit X into Y" or
- "Merge remote-tracking branch 'X' into Y".

It's possible to customize that message by doing `git merge --no-edit -m "Custom message"`, but that overrides the automated one.

I'd like to have both: **A custom message, but also keep the automated one appended to it.**

Is there such a possibility? For example, via a placeholder like `git merge -m "Custom message $AUTOMATIC_MESSAGE"`? (is there such a magic placeholder?)

***Edit 1:***

One way to achieve what I want would be

- Use `git merge` to create a merge with automated message
- Then `git commit --amend` to edit the message in editor and preprend "Custom message"

However, I want the merge to be automated without a stop in editor.

***Edit 2:***

I realized I could proceed as follows in a script: do a merge with an default automatic message, then read that automated merge message post-factum via `git log -1 --pretty=%s`, then amend the message:

```
git merge ...
git commit --amend -m "Custom message: $(git log -1 --pretty=%s)"
```

However, is there a more efficient way by using just `git merge` without amending the commit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I customize git's merge commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148863/how-can-i-customize-gits-merge-commit-message)

Comment: Not fully, I know how to customize the message (`git merge -m`), what I want is to customize && reuse the automated one. I updated my question, along with a 2-step workaround, but maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

(Suboptimal but working self-answer)

It's possible to customize the merge message while preserving the original one by first doing a merge, then reading the automated commit message, then amending it.

```
git merge ...
ORIGINAL_MERGE_MESSAGE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%s)
git commit --amend -m "Custom message: ${ORIGINAL_MERGE_MESSAGE}"
```

(However I'd be happy to have a better solution).

Comment: It seems to be either this, or assume something about the message that `git merge` would generate on its own. There is `git fmt-merge-msg` but it requires input that matches what `git fetch` leaves in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, which is particularly annoying to generate here.