# How to run Git and CVS over the same folder

Tags: git, cvs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to export revision history from mercurial or git to cvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs)
>   [Best practices for using git with CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-cvs)

I have to make a number of changes to a CVS project. These changes cannot be checked in for some time and it's infeasible to create a branch either.

It occurs to me that I could track changes by creating a git project over the top of my CVS snapshot. I can commit my changes to git as I go along and at the end, trivially produce a patch from which I can make a checkin or handoff to someone else.

Is this feasible to do? The biggest issue for me is that I want git to ignore the CVS/ folders and also the bin/ folders where binaries are created. Is this possible to do in some simple fashion.

Comment: http://issaris.blogspot.com/2005/11/cvs-to-git-and-back.html

Comment: This question is really slightly different than those, although they present one possible solution.

Comment: As a matter of fact, after a quick test, I think this a solid alternative to using `git cvsimport`, when you still need to interact with CVS. You can even use `git cvsexportcommit` to commit to CVS. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely possible, just go ahead and create a git repository in the directory, adding the exclusions to `.gitignore`.  As you're just using it as a scratch repo, you don't even need to run an import.