# How to get eclipse sources using git?

Tags: eclipse, git-cvs

I'm trying to get sources from

```
:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse
```

using `git csvserver`. I've just read [Best practices for using git with CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-cvs) and tried different commands including

```
git cvsimport -p xCW2quwz6OlRE -d anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse /cvsroot/eclipse
```

but I don't get past the password prompt (the password in the above line is probably pure nonsense, but it doesn't matter). According to the [eclipse CVS_Howto](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto) the password should be empty (I've tried leaving the `-p` option out as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse login
git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse -C eclipse -r cvs -k <module_name>
```

Choose module_name from http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/ e.g `platform`

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thx, but something is still wrong. I chose "platform" as the module name and I'm getting tons of warnings and nothing downloaded. It makes no sense to me: `WARNING: file /cvsroot/eclipse/org.eclipse.webdav/src/kernel/org/eclipse/webdav/internal/kernel/utils/Attic/SimpleRFC1123DateFormat.java doesn't match strip_path /cvsroot/eclipse/org.eclipse.ant.core/Attic/buildnotes_platform-. ignoring`, and thousands of similar messages.

Comment: The problem is that 'platform' is not actually a module, but a grouping, which doesn't work well with cvsimport. Try 'org.eclipse.swt'

Comment: That's better, it pretends to work. Unfortunately, it does so already since maybe 3 hours and the whole directory contains only 37 MB.

Comment: Long-running process is normal for that kind of action. It collects all the CVS history and rebuilds Git commits from it. The fact that you have to run it only once should relax you a little ;)

Comment: Long-running would be fine, but waiting many hours for *multiple* repos is not. I've found [an eclipse git mirror](http://dev.eclipse.org/git/index.html) and downloaded `git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.git` in 3 minutes. Not sure if this is the same like the CVS repo... but sure that CSV is a terrible thing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are mirrors of most of the CVS projects in a [git mirror](http://dev.eclipse.org/git/index.html) site.

There are also a number of eclipse projects in the process of moving from CVS to Git.  See http://git.eclipse.org/ for a list of projects moving.  SWT is in the process of moving now.