# Equivalent of `git add -p` for cvs

Tags: cvs

I am stuck with cvs (don't ask!) and I was thinking that out of all the goodness of git, there is one that could be approximated reasonably enough: incremental addition of changes, à la `git add -p` followed by `git commit`. Before I try to hack together a solution, does anyone know of an implementation of such a feature?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/ustuehler/git-cvs)?

Comment: Do you have a positive experience with it? It requires direct access to the cvs repo files, doesn't it?

Comment: This isn't a feature available in CVS unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your situation, I would consider using a git interface to a cvs repository.

[Best practices for using git with CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-)
cvs

I do not have experience doing this, so there may be some hidden gotchas I don't know about that would prevent it from working for you, but that is where I would start.

Comment: I have read a lot of that stuff, yes, but I would then need the ability to incrementally import new cvs commits into the converted git repo: often and fast. Unfortunately I haven't found any tool that can correctly convert the repo I have to deal with in the first place and do such incremental imports: `cvs2git` is great but not incremental; `git  cvsimport` is obsolete and erroneous; `fromcvs` ([here](https://github.com/corecode/fromcvs)) creates spurious 'repo-copy' commits after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys, @Tom Lord and @emory, I got motivated to search again for some tool that could incrementally import cvs to git, and I have found one that seem to work fast enough and reliably enough, at least on the repo I have to deal with. I haven't seen it mentioned much, hence that answer. It's called crap-clone (sense of humour!?) and the git repo is https://github.com/rcls/crap.