# Any way to do a local CVS proxy/server?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have an online CVS repository that I need to check code into. However, the server is outside my control and is often down.

So, is there a way to set up some sort of local CVS server/proxy such that I can check my code into the local CVS server regularly and have the local CVS server batch commit the changes to the online CVS repo periodically?

The local repository could possibly run some other SCM system, if that was necessary to prevent conflict with CVS. Online commits could possibly be done manually, or via cron. I'm open to suggestions.

I guess that my main concern would be the problems faced in trying to set up some sort of repository 'hierarchy'.

PS: I'm running Linux all along the 'hierarchy'.

**Edit:** Found a similar item [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/584567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use git locally, and then git-cvsexportcommit would be my suggestion. There's a blog post that talks about this at http://issaris.blogspot.com/2005/11/cvs-to-git-and-back.html although I'll be the first to admit that the export process isn't as easy to use as perhaps it could be.

Comment: sounds like a round-a-bout way of doing things but I can at least understand the logic and work-flow. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend running git locally while continuing to use your CVS server when you have a connection to it.  Here's a nicely-written article that explains how:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.4.4.4/cvs-migration.html

Comment: from what i understand, this flows 'down-stream'. however, i need to ultimately commit changes back to the cvs repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use git as a "frontend" to CVS which will allow to you check-in your changes locally (offline) and then sync them up to the CVS server when your connection is available. There is a bit of a task to setup the environment, but once you get it going the workflow is pretty nice.

See [How to export revision history from mercurial or git to cvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225) for the setup & workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question, but it sounds like you need a [distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) [VCS system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software#Distributed_model).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using a distributed source management system such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/) which support this kind of decentralized source control.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but [CVSup](http://www.cvsup.org/) may do what you need. As others have mentioned, though, a distributed VCS system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/) would probably be better.