# Can we use git-cvs on windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-cvs

I'm comfortable using git, and I prefer it very much over CVS. Unfortunately, in our company, we have to use CVS as a version control system. I was wondering if there was anyway to use git locally while committing to the CVS repo, and I was elated when I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225). Unfortunately, it does not seem to work on Windows. I have Git For Windows (mysysgit) installed on my computer, and when I type `git cvs` or `git cvsimport` in the terminal it says "not a git command". Is there anyway I can use this functionality on windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Cygwin git instead of msysgit, it has this and other functions, like git daemon.

Or you can implement this feature and contribute it to msysgit.

Comment: I was hoping to introduce this to people at work, but there is no way it'll be accepted if you need to do a full cygwin install just to get the functionality. *sigh*

I'll try this out on my computer and accept your answer if it works (and no one comes up with a better method)

Comment: @vedang: the custom setup lets you pick exactly what packages to install so you can get away with a minimal git+dependencies install.

Answer (score 0):

I make that methodology work on Windows, but since our CVS server is Linux I do my export to CVS on that server, and then clone to my Windows machine.  I push back through a staging repository also located on the Linux server.