# Ensuring all git commits make it back to CVS when using git-cvs

Tags: git, git-cvs

I'm using git-cvs, and my general workflow is something like this:

```
...write some code...
$ git commit
$ git cvsexportcommit -c -p -v <asdf>
$ git cvs-import $CVSROOT
$ git pull
```

This generally works fine for pushing my commits back to the CVS server and keeping things in sync.  However, I'm wondering how I will realize that something is missing if I happen to do the "git commit" but forget to export it to the CVS server.

Is there a reasonable way to get a diff between my git repository and the CVS server, so I would know that something hadn't been committed all the way through?  Or perhaps there's a better method of doing this altogether?

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225)

if you do your work on branches and merge them on master for commit (without fast-forward) you can reference the commit parent and it commits all changes back to cvs