# No files in git folder after CVS import

Tags: git, import, cvs, egit

we needed to convert CVS to GIT yesterday. Everything went fine except that I didn't had modules in my CVS therefore I didn't know what module to check out as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/584567).

With the help of [another tutorial](http://www.chem.helsinki.fi/~jonas/git_guides/HTML/CVS2git/CVS2git.html#foot69) everything worked fine.

I sued CVSROOT (immediate direcotry under $CVSROOT) as module name and everything worked fine.

After cloning the git repository now, I can see all the files in Eclipse (Egit).

But when I look in the created git folder I only see the following folders/files

braches (folder) 
config 
description 
HEAD 
hooks (folder) 
index 
info (folder) 
logs (folder) 
objects (folder) 
refs (folder)

where can I find the actual files that in the git repository e.g. (PHP/CSS/Javascript files).

Is there eventually a link somewhere in the Git files to my "old" CVS files?

Hope somebody can help.

Regards

Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Those files* (branches, config, etc.) are the actual git repository. You need to use the `clone` command to checkout the repository into a sandbox you can use:

```
git clone my_repo my_sandbox
```

where `my_repo` is the directory containing *those files*. The `my_sandbox` directory will be created and will contain the your original CVS files (probably from the HEAD branch, depending on how you did your CVS import).

(Incidentally, once your sandbox is checked out, there will be a `.git` directory in it containing the same file structure as *those files*. This allows Git to work in a completely distributed manner and will allow you to switch to different branches and commit changes without the need to be constantly connected to a network.)