# Git to CVS: how do I _regress_?

Tags: git, cvs, regression

Because I'm totally insane (well, there are better reasons but I'm not allowed to talk about them), what's the best approach to port a Git repo to CVS? I haven't used any Git-specific features that I can think of that would hinder the operation, and I know how the authors map.

There are thousands of hits *everywhere* for CVS->Git. I want to go the other way.

Comment: I'm sorry for you.

Comment: So, it seems is everyone. I'd prefer to stick with Git too.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs) and the accepted answer has a section on exporting changes to CVS. Maybe you can create an empty CVS repository and then export your current HEAD to that?

I feel for you though...

Comment: `cvsexportcommit` looks like it might be of use here. I'll have a play with it, and see what I get.

Answer (score 1):

If you by any chance had an option to live with mixed setup, where the server is still git, there is `git cvsserver` command (part of git, though various distributions package it separately, because few people need it). That would allow you to keep using git for some work and still access it with CVS where you are stuck with that.

Comment: I'd also like to stay with Git, but we have to migrate to CVS, unfortunately. It's a shame that there's no obvious way to replicate a CVS repository from an existing CVS server, otherwise I'd use `git-cvsserver` and copy from it.