# CVS Gui frontend with Diff Transaction Logs for Windows

Tags: version-control, cvs, logging, revisions

I'm looking for a CVS GUI Frontend for Windows that has support to view diffs of files on a commit basis.  I know SmartCVS has this feature ( Query | Transactions ) but I am looking for a free or open source version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/) can do what you are looking for, and it's OSS.

Comment: I've tried TortoiseCVS but I couldn't find the feature.  I used to use TortoiseSVN and in the shell menu there is "Show Log" and "Check for Modificition", but I don't see anything similar in TortoiseCVS.  Could you point me to the feature that actually does this?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'd assumed that all TortoiseXXX apps had similar functionality.  It turns out that TortoiseCVS can only show history for a single file, not for a project. It's a little extreme but you could use Git to interface with CVS which would then give you that functionality - [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225) shows how

Comment: This is actually what I am doing right now with CVS/Git/WinMerge. I too am quite surprised that this isn't built into most CVS clients.